# Horizontal Opening Divs having issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a page that contains 8 divs, each one kind of a button.

The layout is basically there are 4 divs on top, 1-4, and 4 divs on bottom, 5-8. Each of these would lead deeper into the site, kind of like a landing page.

I want all the divs to slide off the page when one of them is clicked, reveiling the page underneath them all (Based on whichever one was clicked, a page would be faded into view)

Here is what I have so far (My problem is, I'm not sure how to call the javascript which animates the panels..):

```js
$("#up1").click(function() {
  $(".blockBaseUp").animate({
    "top": "50px",
    'opacity': '1'
  }, "slow");
});

$("#down1").click(function() {
  $(".blockBaseUp").animate({
    "bottom": "-50px",
    'opacity': '0.3'
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
div.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
div.blockBaseUp {
  width: 24.7%;
  height: 49.5%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  float: left;
}
div.blockBaseDown {
  width: 24.7%;
  height: 49.5%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="block1" class="blockBaseUp">
    test1
  </div>
  <div id="block2" class="blockBaseUp">
    test2
  </div>
  <div id="block3" class="blockBaseUp">
    test3
  </div>
  <div id="block4" class="blockBaseUp">
    test4
  </div>

  <br>

  <div id="block5" class="blockBaseDown">
    test5
  </div>
  <div id="block6" class="blockBaseDown">
    test6
  </div>
  <div id="block7" class="blockBaseDown">
    test7
  </div>
  <div id="block8" class="blockBaseDown">
    test8
  </div>
</div>
```

(please view as full page, otherwise it doesn't work properly.. if someone has a fix for this aswell that would be amazing.)

Comment: #up1 and #down1 are missing from your HTML, so your snippet doesn't work.

Comment: @Draco18s Did you read the post? "My problem is, I'm not sure how to call the javascript which animates the panels.."

Comment: He answered your question, you have the selectors `#up1`, `#down1` in your javascript, those ID's are not implemented in your HTML.

Comment: In addition, the details of your question aren't clear as to what you're trying to accomplish.  If you want the single panel you click on to animate, then target that panel with the jQuery selector in both the `.click` and `.animate`

Comment: If you want to run code when someone clicks block1 use this $("#block1").click(function() {...

Comment: @MatthewRath My question was HOW to implement them into my html.

Comment: @Draco18s "I want all the divs to slide off the page when one of them is clicked, revealing the page underneath them all (Based on whichever one was clicked, a page would be faded into view)"

Comment: Yes, you have quoted your question.  My problem is that it is not clear and understandable.  You have used the word "page" to mean two different things, for instance.

Comment: @Draco18s No, they mean the same thing. I click any of the panels, they all slide off the page, and then a new page is faded into view where they used to be. I'm not asking how to do anything with the rest of the page, my specific question is how to implement the javascript to work with my panels to "slide off the page when one of them is clicked"

Comment: Please define "page" in this context.  Do you mean the browser view area, do you mean the content, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Draco18s The webpage. For example, the divs strech across the entire browser viewer, lets define that as the "page" - when one of them is clicked, they should all (The top ones up, and the bottom ones down) slide off the page, and then another div, or perhaps another file will be faded in using jquery. I just want them all to slide at the same time out of view when one of them is clicked.

Comment: Ah ha, see, there you just used two different definitions where previously you used the same word ("view window" and "other content").  Still, if you want to have someone click on one of the divs and all the divs move, then use a selector that selects all of the divs, as OneTwo suggested: `$(".blockBaseUp").click(function() {...`

Comment: Also just on a side note, most animations will perform terribly on mobile platforms stick with css transforms and opacity changes for smooth performance as Paul Lewis points out in his [examination of Jank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrA85a4ZIaM).